# How python execute the slice [1:] of a list with only one element?

Tags: python

Once I wrote a while loop calculation, in the loop there is a list of string (cannot apply pop or del) and every time in the loop, I bind the list's name to it's slice [1:]. Sometimes, problem occurs saying "index out of range", so I guess that's because when the list is a singleton, it's slice [1:] cannot be executed.
However, when I write in interactive window like this:

```
>>>num=[1]
>>>num[1:]
[]
```

an empty list is shown here, this make me feel confusing. Why this situation occurs?

In general, I tried to make slice for a singleton, sometimes succeeds, sometimes fails.

Comment: python indexing start with 0. `num[0:]` will work for you

Comment: Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509297/2745495

Comment: This depends on what you mean by 'succeed' and 'fail' - in the example you show here, `[]` is correctly returned because there is nothing to slice, so the result is an empty set. I guess the failure comes when you try to *access* a nonexistent slice.